# Differential cross-section under proton-neutron exchange?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, particle-physics, scattering, scattering-cross-section

I am well aware of the differential cross-section under the first-order Born approximation
$$\frac{\text{d}\sigma}{\text{d}\Omega}^{(1)}=\left(\frac{m}{2\pi\hbar}\right)^2|\langle{\bf k}'|V|{\bf k}\rangle|^2,$$

and the differential cross-section of the usual Yukawa potential
$$V=\frac{g^2}{r}e^{-\mu r}$$

for proton-neutron interaction. However, now I wish to calculate the cross-section for
$$V'=\frac{V}2(1+P)$$

where $P$ is the exchange operator $P|p,n\rangle=|n,p\rangle$. How does this influence the phase space and the Fourier transform?

Here’s my current thought: the spatial profile of the potential is the same regardless of whether neutron/proton-ness is exchanged, and the scattered particles follow the same path in a classical picture. However I’m unsure how $P$ changes the wavefunctions.

Edit: I am told that the differential cross section should be proportional to
$$\left(\frac{q^2+\mu^2}{q^4\sin^2\theta+2q^2\mu^2+\mu^4}\right)^2.$$
However, I have been unable to reverse engineer this.